# Which VBA should I learn?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have to write a database in Access 2010 and i need to use VBA also (I have never used it). A thought that the times came to learn a little about VBA and VB. I would like to read through a VB tutorial also just to know a little bit about that too. But i found a lot of VB for example 6.0, 2005, 2008, 2010. 
My question is: If I want to learn VBA in Access 2010 which VBA version should I study (link would be good), and which version of VB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VBA and VB are not the same, particularly VB in the context of the .NET framework.  If you want to be able to program within Access, then you need *VBA*, **not** VB. Get a book which covers Access VBA - if you don't like Banjoe's suggestion, there are plenty with fewer pages, and tons of material accessible via Google.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Yes i already knew what you say. I know that i need to learn VBA to make programs in Access.
I just beleived that VBA is a specific VB. So i thought that the VBA for Access is just some kind of extension of VB. So to fully understand the language (VBA) i just wanted to learn VB first.

Comment: No - you don't need to learn VB first.  The syntax of VB and VBA is almost identical: if you just learn from a VBA book or other resource you're not missing anything...

Comment: I learned VBA for access, excel (etc...) about 12 years ago. Definitely don't need to learn VB first ... in fact it might slow you down a little. The access book I learned out of was published by Sybex in '99 might be relevant today, but I'm sure there's something more recent out there to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I've always found the WROX books to be fairly comprehensive and full of useful, real-world examples.  For example: [Access-2007-Programmers-Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470047038)

In the beginning try to stick with bound forms/reports as much as possible.  You can do a lot without VBA and once you start custom coding things it tends to snowball.

If you're new to database design make sure you read up on how to properly normalize your data.  Designing your database properly will save you tons of time in the long run.  See: [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878) for one example.

Comment: Thank you very much but 1200 pages is too much for me, i just would like to scar the peak of the mountain, so a little tutorial will be better for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you are asking the wrong question. Access is a point-and-click development tool, not a programming language. So, what you need to learn is how to use Access to create applications. That means creating user interface objects interactively and then extending them with code.

However, one thing to keep in in mind is that A2010 has new powerful macros with branching and logic and error handling. These are quite robust because all the features of the new Access Web Databases (usable with Sharepoint using Access Services, and runnable in a web browser) are built on top of these macros.

So, I would suggest that you invest time in learning how to create web objects in addition to learning how to sprinkle in some VBA code to extend the behavior of your Access UI objects (and the VBA code won't run in a Web database, BTW).

Comment: Thanks for your response! But my question was accurate. I know the Access is a development tool and i can use the point and click technic to make pretty interfaces for the users, just as like you said ,i just wanted to extend the behaviour of my Acces UI objects. I finished the program, it is very good from a beginner like me :) I  love Access and i will now invest the time as you suggest to learn web objects.